# Java How to remove item from nested Array List

Tags: java, list, nested, nested-lists

I have a nested ArrayList as below with boolean values. I want to remove for example 3rd item from all the rows. I tried with a loop but it doesnt resolve `remove` as a method. How should I do this? Many thanks for your help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
     list.get(i).remove(3)// this remove method shows as an error in IDE
 }

true    false   true    false   false   false
false   false   true    false   true    true
```

Comment: what's the type of `list`? perhaps you are using raw types.

Comment: your list look like `List<List<Boolean>> list`

Comment: @Eran It's a list of List<Instance> listInstances = new ArrayList<Instance>(); and the class Instance has vals = new ArrayList<Boolean>(); Let me know if it explains a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... It's a list of `List<Instance> listInstances = new
>   ArrayList<Instance>();` and the class `Instance` has `vals = new
>   ArrayList<Boolean>();` ....

In this case your solution can look like :

```
public static Instance deleleNthElement(Instance instance, int index) {
    instance.getVals().remove(index - 1);
    return instance;
}
```

then with stream you can call the method like so :

```
int index = 3;
listInstances = listInstances.stream()
          .map(instance -> deleleNthElement(instance, index))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I only want to remove the 3rd item. Would this keep the first 3?

Comment: @user4046073 I thought you want to delete the first three element, check my edit I think you need that solution instead the first

Comment: Thanks. Which package do I need to import? I added import java.util.List; but that did not work.. it does not resolve subList and Collectors. I imported import java.util.*; too I am running Java java 11.0.2

Comment: @user4046073 it seems you are using subList in `Instance`, instead you have to use it in List, check my 3rd edit, maybe it can help you

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you think there's a generic way of removing n th element? That 3rd was an example

Comment: am trying to make it a generic method to remove n th item. However Collectors can still not be resolved tho

Comment: @user4046073 yes there are, I was wrong, I think all you need is `remove`, check my answer and gives me a feedback please

Comment: Thanks but instance.getVals() is the same as my `get(i) ` right? both return a row (ArrayList of Booleans)? and which package do I need to resolve Collectors?

Comment: @user4046073 please edit your question and put the Instance class and more code please to understand more, in your case you have `List<Instance> listInstances` and each instance have `List<Boolean> vals`, so to remove a val from each vals of each instanace you have to get the vals and remove the element from it, again show me more code so I can help you

Comment: Thanks! yes in that loop I should do get(i).vals.remove(attIndex); Thanks very much for your help along the way

Comment: @user4046073 exactly because Instance not have `remove` method but List do, good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

I see no error in your logic, I believe you are missing a ';' from the end of the remove(3).
By the way, List is an Interface, you will need to instanciate as an ArrayList (or some such).

Comment: Thanks. Yes sorry I have that ; in my code. But somehow that remove does not get resolved. I could remove a whole row but not the n th item in that row

Answer (score 1):

I strung the following together, seems to do what you intended:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<Boolean> row1 = new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[] {true,false,true,true}));
        List<Boolean> row2 = new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[] {true,true,false,true}));
        List<List<Boolean>> list = Arrays.asList(new ArrayList[] {(ArrayList) row1, (ArrayList) row2});

        for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            list.get(i).remove(3);// this remove method shows as an error in IDE
        }
        for (List<Boolean> ll : list) {
            for (Boolean l : ll) {
                System.out.print(l + ",");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```